# Sound not playing on device but works on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, avaudioplayer, audio

Yes I have looked around.

```
var congratzSound = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Sweg.aiff", withExtension: "aiff")
var congratzPlayer:AVAudioPlayer? = AVAudioPlayer()
congratzPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: congratzSound, error: nil)
if let congratzPlayer = audioPlayer {
            congratzPlayer.play()
        }
```

This code complies fine, the file is in the Supporting Files section AND being coppied to the device.
What am I doing wrong? Is the file extension not playable? Is the congratzSound set up wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following should solve your problem:

var congratzSound = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Sweg", withExtension: "aiff")

If that doesn't work, try:

var congratzSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sweg", ofType: "aiff")!)

Also, please check whether the file name is as-it-is (Sweg.aiff) in your code project and it is present in your app folder.

It is likely that your device is looking for Sweg.aiff.aiff while trying to play the sound, which obviously doesn't exist